# Issue with "native" color for font symbols

Tags: c#, itext7

I have an issue with an embbeded font in my `iText7` program concerning the rendered color of the text. Let me show you:

[Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArmwPwH8RG7yuuUKu7AqLDa9zja17g?e=k4Xw45) is the font. When I use this font in word, I can do the following by entering "aaaddd":

[image: Word]

So here is my code:

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout;
using ConsoleApp1.Properties;
using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Font;

var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\test.pdf";

var symbol = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(Resources.swsymbolsFRcolor_Regular, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);

var writer = new PdfWriter(path);
var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
var document = new Document(pdf);

var paragraph1 = new Paragraph("aaaddd");
paragraph1.SetFont(symbol);

document.Add(paragraph1);

document.Close();
```

The problem is that the generated symbols are in black and white:

[image: Generated PDF]

Using Word, sometimes, I found a similar behavior. I have to set the color to "auto" to restore the "native" color of the symbols:

[image: Same(?) bug in Word]

But I can't find any "auto" or "native" color in the iText7 SDK.

There are several other fonts that do the same things, but none of those I tried worked.

Comment: Where did you font come from? What type of font is it?

Comment: @NetMage: you can download the font, the link is in the post. It's a True Type Font.

Comment: I prefer not to download random Internet links. I believe your issue is with creating a PDF font from a TrueType font that includes color. PDF Fonts can't include color. If you had the pdfCalligraph add-on, that may help, but I am not positive that works with color.

Answer (score 0):

PDF fonts are generally monochrome by definition as a vector with flag to fill so by default all are black, you can individually set a font fill colour different to the outer stroke (as shown below) for "ASDAaaaddd" but its "unexpected".

These characters were place as default black then the group edited, so for your example they would need to be two groups.

PDF was designed before SVG fonts WOOF or emojis so coloured characters are best added as html vectors then reprinted as pdf equivalent objects.

[image]

Don't forget to embed the font but that font did not embed in my test, however it does say its editable ?
[image]

Comment: Why does Word have default colors for the symbols in the font, then?

Comment: But your answer is about the font, not about the document. Or is `CreateFont` converting from some other (TrueType?) format to PDF Font format? In which case, would converting to Type3 preserve color?

Comment: I am not sure to understand how to solve my issue with your answer. I tried to set the stroke and fill color as you proposed in iText7 (`new Text("a").SetFont(symbolFont).SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLACK).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.GREEN)`) but it does not work. Only the fill color is applied.